# Can't activate virtual environment in Miniconda

Tags: python, conda, miniconda

When I create a virtual environment in Miniconda on Windows 8 and activate it in PowerShell ("activate env"), it says the environment is being activated, but upon typing "conda env list", it shows me that I'm still in the root environment. I checked the envs folder in Miniconda, and the folder with the env is there and seems to be fine with a Python distribution and everything, but for some reason I'm unable to go into the environment itself. For some reason, it works when I use the Command Prompt instead, but this isn't an ideal solution, since I'd like to be able to do everything in PowerShell.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

activate currently doesn't support Powershell. You'll need to modify your path manually, or else call the full path to the Python in the environment.

Comment: What do you mean by "...call the full path..."?

Comment: Like `"C:\Users\Your Username\Miniconda\envs\envname\python.exe"`.