# Conda-build version not installed

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

```
C:\Users\%USER%>conda info
Current conda install:

             platform : win-32
        conda version : 3.16.0
  conda-build version : not installed
       python version : 2.7.10.final.0
     requests version : 2.7.0
     root environment : C:\Users\%USER%\Miniconda  (writable)
  default environment : C:\Users\%USER%\Miniconda
     envs directories : C:\Users\%USER%\Miniconda\envs
        package cache : C:\Users\%USER%\Miniconda\pkgs
         channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-32/
                        https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch/
                        https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-32/
                        https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/
          config file : None
    is foreign system : True

# NOTE:
#     root directory 'C:\Users\%USER%\Miniconda' is uninitialized
```

I see my root directory is not initialized.

Additionally when I try to install a package (pandas eg) I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\%USER%>conda install pandas
Error: This installation of conda is not initialized. Use 'conda create -n
envname' to create a conda environment and 'source activate envname' to
activate it.

# Note that pip installing conda is not the recommended way for setting up your
# system.  The recommended way for setting up a conda system is by installing
# Miniconda, see: http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/index.html
```

I assume they are related but I am not sure the course of action.

I had anaconda/python27 up and running but wanted to update matplotlib and thought to reinstall python with conda to be "up to date".

The error is documented [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1420), but to be honest I do not really get it.

I regret this as it is a bit tough to get up and running again!

Comment: How did you reinstall python with conda?

Comment: @asmeurer will respond soon with full detail. apologies on delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem, but with Anaconda on Windows 8.1. 
The python env variables are set from a previous python install. 
The installer did not update (user)PYTHONHOME, (system)PYTHON_DIR, and  (system)PYTHONPATH, so I manually set them to /Users/me/Anaconda/.

```
conda update conda
```

gave the error mentioned above. I added a new conda environment...

```
conda create -n notebook jupyter 
activate notebook
```

which succeeded, but...

```
conda info --envs
```

...gives...

```
notebook  C:\Users\<me>\Anaconda\envs\notebook 
root  *   C:\Users\<me>\Anaconda
```

...and...

conda info
  ...
  # NOTE: root directory 'C:\Users\me\Anaconda' is uninitialized.

I suspect that the installer failed due to the presence of the environment variables. I deleted the environment variables and the /Users/me/Anaconda directory, then installed miniconda. 
All seems to be well now.

Note:
I had previously installed python at least three different ways.
{Chocolatey, Anaconda(all)[failed], python msi}

Comment: Activating the environment from powershell is still broken, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30054372/cant-activate-virtual-environment-in-miniconda

Comment: It's generally best to have `PYTHONHOME` and `PYTHONPATH` unset.

Comment: Upon deleting the environment variables it appears to be a cleaner install.

Comment: *" The python env variables are set from a previous python install"* of what: Anaconda, or some other distro? In any case, just delete them.